# Vuejs v-model with 2-dimensional array dynamic name

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

How can you name a dynamic v-model with 2 dynamic variables? If I used only 1 dynamic variable like `v-model="shirt_count[brand]"` it works, however using `v-model="shirt_count[brand][color]"` does not work, code below for sample:

```
<template>  
<div v-for="brand in brands" >
    <div v-for="color in colors" >
        <input type="text" v-model="shirt_count[brand][color]" />
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['brands', 'colors'],
    data(){
       return {
           shirt_count: []
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to have an output like below, that's why I need it 2 dimensional:

```
shirt_count: [
  'brand_a': [
       'red': 5
       'blue': 4
   ],
  'brand_b': [
       'red': 1
       'blue': 3
  ]
]
```

Comment: It does only work if that value exist, if for some reason brand is equal to {}, and does not have the color your are looking for, it will not work. In your scenario, you will need to have every brand and color keys in your data that match the props, like `return  { shirt: {brand1: {color1: '#fff'}} }`

Comment: A more robust solution would be to do : `:modelValue="shirt[brand][color]" @update:modelValue="onUpdateModelValue"` and in that method, check if the brand and color exist and if not create it, then update the value

Comment: https://vue3-yenilikler.vercel.app/#/detail/v-model  take a look here

Answer (score 0):

#### Re-build by your code (not working, see error)

```js
// CDN Vue Import
const { createApp, ref, reactive } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    // Simulate props
    const { brands, colors } = reactive({
      brands: ['brand_a', 'brand_b'],
      colors: ['red', 'blue'],
    })
    
    // Simulate data.shirt_count
    const shirt_count = ref({})
    
    return { brands, colors, shirt_count }
  },
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Solution</h2>
  <div v-for="brand in brands" >
    <div v-for="color in colors" >
      <input type="text" v-model="shirt_count[brand][color]" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>shirt_count[]</h2>
  <div>{{ shirt_count }}</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that `shirt_count` is an object where `brands` "key-value" pairs can be declared, but in order to create a sub-objects, you need to declare them first before inserting the `colors` key-value pairs into the sub-object. Therefore, you need to process the `props.brands` and `props.colors` and build the `shirt_count` using them.

#### Solution (working, build shirt_count, declare objects)

```js
// CDN Vue Import
const { createApp, ref, reactive } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    // Simulate props
    const { brands, colors } = reactive({
      brands: ['brand_a', 'brand_b'],
      colors: ['red', 'blue'],
    })
    
    // Simulate data.shirt_count
    const shirt_count = ref({})
    
    // Solution --> build structure
    brands.forEach((brand) => {
      shirt_count.value[brand] = {}
      colors.forEach((color) => shirt_count.value[brand][color] = null)
    })
    
    return { brands, colors, shirt_count }
  },
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Solution</h2>
  <div v-for="brand in brands" >
    <div v-for="color in colors" >
      <input type="text" v-model="shirt_count[brand][color]" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>shirt_count[]</h2>
  <div>{{ shirt_count }}</div>
</div>
```